# Connect servers in Internet via OpenVPN

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, linux-networking

I'm trying to connect multiple servers (Ubuntu Server 20.04) on the internet so they are in same private network and can share services that are only accessible through this private network (like server administration etc.). I did some search before but no answer was satisfying my scenario.

Scenario is: I got one server with OpenVPN Server up and running and generated client certificates for two other servers to connect to OpenVPN server.

The script I used for this is [this](https://github.com/angristan/openvpn-install) here at github. This works fine.

Now's the problem that I'm able to connect the clients to the OpenVPN server but I'm not able to connect to one of the clients via SSH or otherwise. Over VPN no problem.

**Question:** How do I get clients accessible through internet? As far as I know problem seems to be that OpenVPN server propagates a new default gateway for clients so traffic only can come through VPN. Thank you in advise. Configuration as following:

**server.conf**

```
port 1194
proto udp6
dev tun
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
keepalive 10 120
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "dhcp-option DNS 1.0.0.1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 1.1.1.1"
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
server-ipv6 fd42:42:42:42::/112
tun-ipv6
push tun-ipv6
push "route-ipv6 2000::/3"
push "redirect-gateway ipv6"
dh none
ecdh-curve prime256v1
tls-crypt tls-crypt.key 0
crl-verify crl.pem
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
auth SHA256
cipher AES-128-GCM
ncp-ciphers AES-128-GCM
tls-server
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-cipher TLS-ECDHE-ECDSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256
client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/ccd
status /var/log/openvpn/status.log
verb 3
```

**client.conf**

```
client
proto udp
explicit-exit-notify
remote {server IP} 1194
dev tun
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
verify-x509-name {server name} name
auth SHA256
auth-nocache
cipher AES-128-GCM
tls-client
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-cipher TLS-ECDHE-ECDSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256
ignore-unknown-option block-outside-dns
setenv opt block-outside-dns # Prevent Windows 10 DNS leak
verb 3
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to push routes for the VPN reachable systems but not default routes.  To do this remove the statements pushing the gateway from the server -

```
  push "redirect-gateway ipv6"
```

And

```
  push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
```

You probably need to push routes for the other clients, something like adding

```
 push "10.8.0.0 255.255.0.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `client-to-client` to your server conf.

Answer (score 0):

```
setenv opt block-outside-dns # Prevent Windows 10 DNS leak
```

maybe you use server name to connect, and ur script  blocked the adrress (DNS).

try remove it.